# The new line code "\n" and/or @NewLine does not add new line to field

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I'm getting document history, adding "\n" and existing document history. Code executes without any error. But when I see it in web everything on one line. In notes client, document history is shown as one line of activity.

Tried with @Newline and same issue.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Here is sample code:

```
var myvar="\n"
var h=getComponent("docHistory1").getValue();
var msg="Stage 2 - LAB Manager approved and completed check. Send to Chemist: " + unm + "  + dt1;
document1.setValue("DocHistory", h + myvar + msg);
document1.save();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Multiline Edit Box `xp:inputTextarea` instead of a Computed field `xp:text` and set it to Read only `readonly="true"`.

As an alternative you could still use a Computed field replacing all `'\n'` with `'<br />'` and setting `escape="false"`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. readonly = "true" does not save the component to notes document. After readonly flag it saves the component. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, `readonly="true"` is only necessary if field doesn't have to be editable. I thought you just wanted to show the history. Then without readonly parameter it's even easier :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I kept it read only, added data as notes field (which I forgot to mention in my previou post. I do apologize for that) and changed the value thru button. It saved the value but <br/> appeared as it is as shown here: 0<br/>Stage 2 Accepted:- Mohan Gangan - 4/7/14: test1. But goodnews is @NewLine function adds new line. I do appreciate your quick help. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to apear `<br />` as a newline then you have to set `escape="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an alternative solution, you could use a style on the computed text component with "white-space:pre" (or pre-line or pre-wrap, see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) for the differences) and that would preserve the newlines in the content.